# Not getting any results back from Fuse.js with Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, fuse.js

So I'm fairly new to Vue and I'm trying to make a customer list search work with Fuse.js.
I do get the array of customers back and it's being assigned to customer_search. my keys are populated properly and the only issue is that results doesn't return anything. I'm wondering if I need to structure my customer array differently or am I missing something else altogether?

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
<template>  
<div>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Search</h1>
        <input type="text" class="input-search" value="" v-model="query">
        <p v-html="results"></p>
        <p v-for="info in data" >{{info}}</p>
    </div>
</div>

</template>    

<script>
import Fuse from 'fuse.js'
import $ from 'jquery'
import PageService from '../../common/services/PageService'

const Search = {

    data(){
        return {
            data: {},
            fuse: {},
            results: {},
            query: '',
            options: {
                keys: [
                    'id',
                    'name',
                    'company',
                ],
                minMatchCharLength: 3,
                shouldSort: true,
                threshold: 0.5
            },
        }
    },
    methods:{
        runQuery(query){
            if(query.length >= 3)
                this.results = this.fuse.search(query)
        },
    },
    computed:{
        customers: function(){
            return this.data
        },
        customer_search: function(){
            return Object.values(this.data)
        },
    },
    watch: {
        query: function(){
            this.runQuery(this.query)

        }
    },
    created(){
        this.fuse = new Fuse(this.customer_search, this.options)
        if(this.$store.state.search != ''){
            this.query = this.$store.state.search
        }
        PageService.getSearchObject().then((response)=>{
            this.data = response.data
        }).catch((err)=>{
            console.log('Error')
        });
    },
}
export default Search
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your `runQuery` method is created before your `this.fuse` get created so the `this.fuse` inside your `runQuery` method is not up-to-date.

Maybe try:

```
methods:{
        runQuery(query){
            if(query.length >= 3)
                this.results = new Fuse(this.customer_search, this.options).search(query)
        },
    },
```

Comment: You were right my friend! it works fine now, thank you so much for your help